# Simplification of algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have got a big algebraic expression for function $\vec{a} = \vec{a}(s)$, that i simplified to the form
$$\frac{d \vec{a}}{ds} + \frac{a - \sin a}{a^3} (\vec{a} (\vec{a} \cdot \frac{d \vec{a}}{ds}) - a^2 \frac{d \vec{a}}{ds}) - \frac{1 - \cos a}{a^2} [\vec{a} \times \frac{d \vec{a}}{ds}],$$

Is that final version or could it be simplified to more simpler?

Comment: For starters, the second term of the second term cancels out with the first term ($ a(-a^2)/a^3 = -1$). The rest depends on any additional properties. And... just to clarify, is $\alpha$ just the magnitude of $\vec{\alpha}$? Is this related to axis-angle representation of rotations? Because it really looks like some sort of rotation formula, maybe rotation along a path?

Comment: Yes, $a = |\vec{a}|$. If it coincides with some known formula, it is of interest too, of course!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Did you take a derivative of the angular velocity vector to get how much it rotates under its own rotational influence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is better:

$$-\sin\alpha \,\hat{\alpha}\left(\hat{\alpha}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d\vec{\alpha}}{ds}\right)-\cos\alpha\,\hat{\alpha}\times \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d\vec{\alpha}}{ds} $$

The first term is just the contribution of growth of $\vec{\alpha}$ in magnitude while the second is just the change in direction (growth in magnitude has no effect). I used $\hat{\alpha}$ for normalized vector notation.

Using this decomposition into magnitude effect and direction effect, we no longer have to worry about separating derivative from normalization - because $d/ds(\vec{\alpha}/\alpha)\neq (d\vec{\alpha}/ds)/\alpha$, I couldn't just carry $\alpha$ inside the derivative, but it turns out that the projection removes the extra terms you get with this move.

$$-\sin\alpha \,\hat{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d\alpha}{ds}\right)-\cos\alpha\,\hat{\alpha}\times\frac{d\hat{\alpha}}{ds}$$

The first is just a relative change in magnitude, the second is just a rate of rotation of direction in space.

Nevertheless, you should recheck your whole procedure. I think I know what you are doing and it looks plausible, but there could be missing terms. Maybe you could simplify a bit in earlier stages to get a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I was solving the equation for two unknowns $\vec{u}(s,t), \vec{w}(s,t)$
$$\partial_t \vec{u} = \partial_s \vec{w} - [\vec{w} \times \vec{u}].$$
Its general solution is given by formula
$$\vec{u} = \partial_s \vec{a} + \frac{a - \sin a}{a^3} (\vec{a} (\vec{a} \cdot \partial_s \vec{a}) - a^2 \partial_s \vec{a}) - \frac{1 - \cos a}{a^2} [\vec{a} \times \partial_s \vec{a}],$$
$$\vec{w} = \partial_t \vec{a} + \frac{a - \sin a}{a^3} (\vec{a} (\vec{a} \cdot \partial_t \vec{a}) - a^2 \partial_t \vec{a}) - \frac{1 - \cos a}{a^2} [\vec{a} \times \partial_t \vec{a}].$$